# Looking for a Dual Listbox with AngularJS and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I am looking for a component like this to be included in my project:

[image]

http://geodan.github.io/duallistbox/sample-100.html

I want to install it with npm.

The problem is that I tested some of the examples which are over there, but without success (I get exceptions, or there is no npm, only bower)

These are the examples I tested.

- https://github.com/alexklibisz/angular-dual-multiselect-directive
- https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-bootstrap-duallistbox
- http://www.bootply.com/mRcBel7RWm

Any recommendations about one with AngularJs, Bootstrap, and npm?

Comment: can you post the exception ?

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your requirement: [Dual list Box](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/BWWsCe)

### app.js

```js
angular.module('plunker', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, utils) {
    $scope.list1 = [],
      $scope.list2 = [];

    utils.insertData($scope.list1, 5);

  })
  .factory('utils', function Utils() {
    return {
      insertData: function(list, numItems) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
          list.push({
            id: i + 1,
            title: 'item' + (i + 1)
          });
        }
      },
      getIndexesFromList: function(list) {
        var newList = [];
        for (var i in list) {
          if (typeof list[i].id === "number" && newList.indexOf(list[i].id) === -1) newList.push(list[i].id)
        }
        return newList;
      },
      getAllSelectedItems: function(list) {
        var newList = [];
        newList = list.filter(function(el) {
          return el.active === true;
        });
        return newList;
      },
      addListIfNoExists: function(list2, newListToAppend) {
        var indexes = this.getIndexesFromList(list2);
        var newList = [];
        for (var i in newListToAppend) {
          if (indexes.indexOf(newListToAppend[i].id) === -1) list2.push(newListToAppend[i])
        }
        return list2;
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('dualList', function(utils) {

    function _controller($scope) {
      $scope.selectAllItem = function(list, checked) {
        list.map(function(item) {
          item.active = checked
          return item;
        });
      };
      $scope.getAllSelectedItems = function(list) {
        return utils.getAllSelectedItems(list);
      }
      $scope.moveItemToRightList = function() {
        var newListToAppend = $scope.list1.filter(function(el) {
          if (el.active === true) {
            el.active = false;
            return el;
          }
        });
        if (newListToAppend.length > 0) {
          $scope.list1 = $scope.list1.filter(function(el) {
            return utils.getIndexesFromList(newListToAppend).indexOf(el.id) === -1;
          });
          $scope.list2 = utils.addListIfNoExists($scope.list2, newListToAppend);
          if ($scope.list1.length === 0) $scope.checked1 = false;
        }

      };
      $scope.moveItemToLeftList = function() {
        var newListToAppend = $scope.list2.filter(function(el) {
          if (el.active === true) {
            el.active = false;
            return el;
          }
        });
        if (newListToAppend.length > 0) {
          $scope.list2 = $scope.list2.filter(function(el) {
            return utils.getIndexesFromList(newListToAppend).indexOf(parseInt(el.id)) === -1;
          });
          $scope.list1 = utils.addListIfNoExists($scope.list1, newListToAppend);
          if ($scope.list2.length === 0) $scope.checked2 = false;
        }

      };
    }
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: true,
      controller: _controller,
      templateUrl: "dualList.html"
    };
  });
```

### dualList.html

```html
<div class="container">
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="dual-list list-left col-md-5">
      <div class="well text-right">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox"
                       ng-model="checked1"
                       ng-click="selectAllItem(list1, checked1)">
                    Todo {{getAllSelectedItems(list1).length}}/{{list1.length}}
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
              <input type="text"
                     name="SearchDualList"
                     ng-model="search1"
                     class="form-control"
                     placeholder="search" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <a class="list-group-item"
             href=""
             data-id="{{item.id}}"
             ng-click="item.active = !item.active"
             ng-class="{active: item.active}"
             ng-repeat="item in list1|filter: search1">{{item.title}}</a>
        </ul>
        <p ng-if="(list1 | filter:search1).length == 0">Sin Datos</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-arrows col-md-1 text-center">
      <button ng-click="moveItemToLeftList()"
              class="btn btn-default btn-sm move-left">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </button>
      <button ng-click="moveItemToRightList()"
              class="btn btn-default btn-sm move-right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="dual-list list-right col-md-5">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox"
                       ng-model="checked2"
                       ng-click="selectAllItem(list2, checked2)">
                    Todo {{getAllSelectedItems(list2).length}}/{{list2.length}}
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
              <input type="text"
                     name="SearchDualList"
                     ng-model="search2"
                     class="form-control"
                     placeholder="search" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <a class="list-group-item"
             href=""
             data-id="{{item.id}}"
             ng-click="item.active = !item.active"
             ng-class="{active: item.active}"
             ng-repeat="item in list2|filter: search2">{{item.title}}</a>
        </ul>
        <p ng-if="(list2 | filter:search2).length == 0">Sin Datos</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link data-require="font-awesome@*" data-semver="4.3.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <dual-list data-list1="list1" data-list2="list2"></dual-list>
  </body>
</html>
```

### style.css

```css
.dual-list .list-group {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.list-arrows {
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.list-arrows button {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.list-group-item.active, .list-group-item.active:hover, .list-group-item.active:focus {
  border-color: white;
}
.input-group-addon {
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this npm for angular 2/4 just you need to install with npm
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-dual-list-box

Comment: The question about AngularJS not Angular!

Comment: @Al-Mothafar The title says Angular. It is the fault of the person who asked

Comment: @SK. Do you just read the title? you never look into the question itself or code? AngularJS mentioned already in the last line if you see what the person who asked wrote. anyway title edited.

Answer (score -1):

I think [this](https://angularscript.com/dual-list-box-component-angular-4/) link will help you.